# Combining Bits - Combining Characters to Integers C++

Tags: c++

I have an idea on how to make a header of a file more efficient (for an assignment) but I want to know if I can carry out the implementation.

Is it possible to read 24 bits from a file and then put it into an integer and have it retain its value?

Let's say I have:

00000000 00000001 00000000 = 256

Can I read this from a file, separate it into three characters, and then combine these characters into one integer such that the value 256 is retained? Such that the end result would be:

00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 = 256

Comment: You will need to read 3 8-bit values and place them, using binary arithmetic, into the 32-bit integer.  Please clarify *retained*, is the duration only during a function?  during the program?  after program quits?

Comment: During the program, I mean, sorry. As for binary arithmetic - would I shift the values and then set the bits in their proper positions? I think this could work then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char a, b, c;
if (f >> std::noskipws >> a >> b >> c)
{
    int n = a * 256 * 256 + b * 256 + c;
    // use n...
}
else
    std::cerr << "unable to read 3 characters from file\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int combine_chars(char a, char b, char c) {
    char arr[4] = {c, b, a, '\0'};
    return *(int *)arr;
}
```

This is assuming little-endian representation of the integer, which means that the least significant byte has the smallest index. Basically the function creates an array of the 3 characters with a trailing 0 (since the most significant byte is `'\0'`, or most significant 8 bits are 0). The least significant byte is `c`, then since the second least significant byte is `1` from the example, that becomes `1 << 8` which is `256`. The array in memory is:

```
c b a '\0'
```

This then gets casted to an integer pointer `(int *)` which then gets dereferenced to the integer value and returned.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this:

```
int getNumberFromStdin() {
    std::string numberStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;
        numberStr += s;
    }
    int number = 0;
    for (const auto c : numberStr) {
        number = (number << 1) + (c - '0');
    }
    return number;
}
```